# imgNote tags won't load on IE and Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, google-chrome, cross-browser

We made ascript using `imgNote` plugin (https://github.com/waynegm/imgNotes).

Tags are loading fine on Firefox but not on IE and Chrome.

Please check it at http://fluidblueprint.com

Temp login for testing:

- user: pranaya@creator9.com
- password: pppp

Thank you.

Comment: Please put the non-working code here and try to reproduce the issue on jsfiddle.

Comment: Hi, here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/reenku/8cf9N/

Comment: Your script works the same way for me on those 3 browsers : a plan appears, i click the "Add your marker" button and then I'm able to click the plan and add markers. What is the problem ?

Comment: I noticed there is weird things in your script, like `jQuery(document).ready(function($) { $(document).ready(function() {`. Try to correct these points and clean your scripts before debugging, that's really messy atm.

Comment: Hi Thank you for your help. You can check the error properly inside the live url i have given above. Pre saved markers wont appear on IE and Chrome, where as they come fine in Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

I got it working. FYI, it was working fine on my Chrome (Version 35.0.1916.153 m), only IE was not good.

You have to change this part :

```
var $img = $("#image").imgNotes();
$img.one("load",function(){
    $img.imgNotes("import", [{x: "0.39024895115902547", y:"0.3377519191655898", note:"Great Room Test Marker", id:"3", sid:"1", nid:"47"},...]);
});
```

To :

```
var $img = $("#image").imgNotes();
$img.imgNotes("import", [{x: "0.39024895115902547", y:"0.3377519191655898", note:"Great Room Test Marker", id:"3", sid:"1", nid:"47"},...]);
```

Finally, the thing is to directly gives markers and not to do it on image load event diring. I guess that the load event is not fired on IE, or maybe to early (before the line execution).

You should create an issue ticket on the github project, IMO this behaviour is anormal.